# Is it possible to find coordinates on a picture?

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation

I explain myself better. If I have the picture of a map from a game, is it possible to input the coordinates of a NPC for example (X 700; Y 200) then press the search-button and make it appear on that map (with any sorta mark).

I hope I was clear enough, but since I am sure I wasn't, please check the picture attached [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3q3o3.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can get to the exact (X, Y) location using CSS. `X` can be `margin-left` and `Y` `margin-top` of your marker.

Example in jQuery:

```
$('#map').css({ 
               'margin-left': X + 'px',
               'margin-top': Y + 'px'
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but sadly that wasn't what I was looking for. Have you seen the picture in the link? I would like to have a way for people to insert the coordinates and have these coordinates show the point on map with a marker.

Comment: Then I think you asked in a misleading way. You want to ask how to pass the input values to CSS?

Comment: Yes. How do I build a search form that is able to change the css each time a new value is added?

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML markup should be something like this.

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="img-src" alt="map" style="width:100%;">
  <div id="marker">Marker</div>
</div>
```

Your css classes

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#marker {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Your js should have following code for placing marker

```
const marker = document.getElementById('marker');
marker.style.left = `${x}px`;
marker.style.top= `${y}px`;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but sadly that wasn't what I was looking for. Have you seen the picture in the link? I would like to have a way for people to insert the coordinates and have these coordinates show the point on map with a marker.

Comment: In the above code x and y are coordinates that user is entering. I think if that is not the case I am unable to fully understand (took a look at the image as well).

Comment: I don't understand how can I make a search form to look for the coordinates into an image. I don't know how to "link" the form and the div where the image is contained...